# Por que ao usar ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ou REPLACE, temos alteração em 2 linhas?

Tags: mysql, sql

### Exemplo

Ao executar qualquer um dos 2 comandos, é retornada a mensagem:

> 2 row(s) affected

**Query**:

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO `banco`.`tabela` (`id`, `resumo`, `descricao`, `grupo`, `solicitante`) 
VALUES ('129', 'Teste 2', 'Testando 2', '5', '1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE resumo = 'onduplicate', descricao = 'onduplicate', grupo = 5, solicitante = 1;
```

`REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE INTO `banco`.`tabela` (`id`, `resumo`, `descricao`, `grupo`, `solicitante`) 
VALUES ('129', 'Teste 2', 'Testando 2', '5', '1');
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- **Por que** o banco de dados executa **2 alterações**?

  - Quais seriam elas?
  - **As 2 formas** de fazer **executam os mesmos processos**?
- Teria alguma **vantagem** uma sobre a outra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo a informação do manual relativo ao `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> Com o `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, o `mysql_affected_rows()` é 1 se a linha
>   é inserida como uma nova e 2 se uma linha existente for atualizada.

Quanto ao `REPLACE`: [REPLACE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

> Quando você utilizar um comando `REPLACE`, `mysql_affected_rows()`
>   retornará 2 se a nova linha substituir uma linha antiga. Isto é porque
>   uma linha foi inserida depois que a linha duplicada foi deletada.
>
> Este fato torna fácil determinar se `REPLACE` adicionou ou subsitituiu uma
>   linha: verifique se o valor de linhas afetadas é 1 (adicionado) ou 2
>   (substituido).
>
> Note que a menos que a tabela utilize índices `UNIQUE` ou `PRIMARY KEY`, utilizar um comando `REPLACE` não faz sentido. Ele
>   se torna equivalente a um `INSERT`, porque não existe índice a ser usado
>   para determinar se uma nova linha duplica outra.

É possível que o cenário que está a **negrito** seja o que lhe está a acontecer, daí ele devolver o resultado de 2 ao invés de 1.

O manual em PT-BR encontra-se aqui: [Manual de Referência do MySQL 4.1](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-4.1-pt.a4.pdf)

### Diferença entre `REPLACE` e `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

**`REPLACE`**

1. Tenta inserir a linha na tabela
2. Se falhar, apaga linha e insere nova linha

**`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`**

1. Tenta inserir a linha na tabela
2. Se falhar, atualiza a linha

---

**Conclusão** (respondendo às duas novas questões)

Os processos executados são parecidos, mas no caso do `REPLACE` existe um "senão", que é o facto de ele apagar a linha para depois inserir. O `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` é mais seguro nesse aspeto porque apenas atualiza a linha.

Posto isto, a forma mais segura e, quase de certeza, mais rápida em tempo de execução, será a opção `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Te importa em traduzir o quotes? É provável que nem todos os usuários saibam inglês.

Comment: Sim, claro, tem toda a razão. Resposta editada.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Te atrapalharia se eu colocasse na pergunta "se as 2 funções executam os mesmos processos?", pois seria bem interessante e complementaria mais o assunto.

Comment: Não @rbz, claro que não :)

Comment: @JoãoMartins Adicionei, e já até foi mais uma de brinde! rsrs... Mas como vc é mestre no assunto, sei que vai responder facinho! ;)

Comment: Resposta editada para responder às duas novas questões!