# Como fazer replace em todos os campos menos um?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Eu tenho uma tabela com vários campos, e preciso fazer um `insert` ou `replace` em cada linha. Eu recebo os dados vindos de um software e se não existir, insiro, senão substituo.

Eu recebo um `array` que pode ter todos os campos ou só alguns. Só que há 2 campos na tabela que sou eu que adiciono.

```
campo_recebido1
campo_recebido2
campo_recebido3
...
campo_add1
campo_add2
```

Por exemplo, quando o `campo_recebido1` é igual a 1 eu coloco um valor no `campo_add1` e quando `campo_recebido1` é igual a 2 eu coloco um valor no `campo_add2`.

Para fazer isso eu uso o `REPLACE INTO` ajustado automaticamente com os campos recebidos.

Só que eu queria manter sempre o `campo_add1` e o `campo_add2` com os últimos valores possíveis. Para isso eu fiz um trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON table
    FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
          IF NEW.`campo_add1` IS NULL THEN
              SET NEW.`campo_add1` = OLD.`campo_add1`;
          END IF;
          IF NEW.`campo_add2` IS NULL THEN
              SET NEW.`campo_add2` = OLD.`campo_add2`;
          END IF;
       END;
```

Eu testei com UPDATE e com INSERT mas parece não fazer nada.

Como poderei manter sempre os `campo_add` que não são para serem atualizados mas também não são para serem apagado?

---

### EXEMPLOS

**EXEMPLO 1**
Eu recebo `1,1234,"texto"` e executo a query:

`REPLACE INTO table SET camporecebido1 = 1, camporecebido2 = 1234, camporecebido3 = "texto", campo_add1 = 32`

Como podem reparar o `campo_add2` não faz parte da query e ficará a `null`.

**EXEMPLO 2**
De seguida recebo `2,1234,"textoalterado"` e executo a query:

`REPLACE INTO table SET camporecebido1 = 2, camporecebido2 = 1234, camporecebido3 = "textoalterado", campo_add2 = 64`

Como podem reparar o `campo_add1` não faz parte da query, e será apagado, mas eu queria manter o `campo_add1 = 32` da query anterior...

**EXEMPLO 3**
Se entretanto eu receber `1,1234` executo a query:

`REPLACE INTO table SET camporecebido1 =1, camporecebido2 = 1234, campo_add1 = 128`

Ou seja, o `camporecebido3` vai ser colocado a `null`, o `campo_add1` atualizado e queria manter o `meucampo2 = 64` da query anterior.

[Cenário no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e842dc/1)
[Cenário no DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hbtUNcPCpp8DZDWYMZKesy/0)

---

**Na verdade, segundo entendi, o que eu preciso é de um equivalente ao `INSTEAD OF trigger` do SQL Server mas para MySQL.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solução 1

Uma opção que eu usaria, seria o `INSERT` com `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "texto", campo_add1 = "32"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "texto", campo_add1 = "32";

INSERT INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "2", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "textoalterado", campo_add2 = "64"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campo_recebido1 = "2", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "textoalterado", campo_add2 = "64";

INSERT INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_add1 = "128"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_add1 = "128";
```

---

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81cb304/1)

---

**Diferença entre REPLACE e ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

`REPLACE`

1. Tenta inserir a linha na tabela
2. Se falhar, apaga linha e insere nova linha

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

1. Tenta inserir a linha na tabela
2. Se falhar, atualiza a linha

Fonte:
[Por que ao usar ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ou REPLACE, temos alteração em 2 linhas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329245/92908)

---

### Solução 2

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.`campo_add1` IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.`campo_add1` = (SELECT `campo_add1` FROM table1 WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`);
  END IF;
  IF NEW.`campo_add2` IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.`campo_add2` = (SELECT `campo_add2` FROM table1 WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`);
  END IF;
END;//

REPLACE INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "texto", campo_add1 = "32"//
REPLACE INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "2", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_recebido3 = "textoalterado", campo_add2 = "64"//
REPLACE INTO table1 SET id="123", campo_recebido1 = "1", campo_recebido2 = "1234", campo_add1 = "128"//
```

---

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7VM3fgAiSoNcZvmzwqaQ9/0)

---

Como o `REPLACE` há 2 opções conforme visto acima (ou ele dá `INSERT` ou `DELETE` + `INSERT`) a trigger teria que ser do tipo `INSERT` para atender as 2 opções, mas por ser do tipo `INSERT` utilizando `BEFORE` ou `AFTER`, não terá a tabela temporária `DELETED`, tendo que buscar manualmente o valor.

Fonte: [Em trigger temos INSERTED, DELETED, mas e o “UPDATED”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325488/em-trigger-temos-inserted-deleted-mas-e-o-updated)

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso use o UPDATE ao invés do REPLACE

```
UPDATE table SET camporecebido1 = 1, camporecebido2 = 1234, camporecebido3 = "texto", meucampo1 = 32 WHERE XXXX=YYY
```

e

```
UPDATE table SET camporecebido1 = 2, camporecebido2 = 1234, camporecebido3 = "textoalterado", meucampo2 = 64  WHERE XXXX=YYY
```

Lembrando de definir a cláusula WHERE para atualizar apenas os registros desejados.

Comment: Mas nem sempre é update, como eu disse, pode ser insert se não existir. E não quero estar a verificar antes se já existe ou não. Para além disso pode vir com campos vazios (sem campo), e eu estaria a deixar outros campos preenchidos que deveriam ser apagados. Porque eu posso receber só um campo para update e os restantes não recebo mas têm de ser apagados.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com mais um exemplo para explicar melhor.

Comment: Nesse caso é melhor você utilizar a sintaxe: "insert into table values (...)
on duplicate update xxxx=yyyyy;"... Dẽ uma checada nessa sintaxe em https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, mas essa forma tem o mesmo problema no caso dos campos que não recebo, que tem de ser apagados e não tem como. Porque tem de ser transparente, eu nunca sei quantos campos eu vou receber do software, só um identificador, que eu considerei o `camporecebido2` é que é obrigatório. Os outros podem nem vir, e se não vier mais nenhum excepto o ID os outros tem de ser apagados, no caso de já existir o registo.

Comment: Se eles tem de ser apagados, o replace já faz isso

Comment: Mas lá está o replace tem o problema que eu disse acima. que é o `meucampo1` (ou o 2) que tem de se manter, se já estiver definido e não for para alterar.